# Does "heuristic" have an antonym?

Tags: antonyms

As a computer software engineer, I find that "heuristic" seems to be taken de facto, with no acknowledgement of any negative connotations, i.e. aspiring to more explicit, measurable, absolute alternative.

For example when given a set of objects, and the goal of deciding if they are alike or different, a heuristic approach compares one or more attributes of each item, which may not "prove" the decision, but support it.

"Deterministic" is probably the best choice, which might apply in the case one attribute is deemed to be distinct and definite.

Comment: It would be better to say which sense/s of 'heuristic' you mean, with dictionary support. _Left_ , _skew_ , _wrong_ and _overturn_ (arguably) are all antonyms of _right_ , but hardly classmates, never mind near-synonyms.

Comment: Given Computer Science as context: _Deterministic_ algorithms solve the problem with exact decision at every step of the algorithm whereas _non-deterministic_ algorithms solve problems via guessing although typical guesses are made more accurate through the use of _heuristics_. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm

Comment: Later, I was reminded that some computer languages use "duck typing" vs. explicit/strict types.  Classic practical application of heuristic, and wildly popular too.

Answer (score 3):

[Heuristic](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/heuristic) -  proceeding to a solution by trial and error or by rules that are only loosely defined

[Analytics](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/analytics) - the systematic computational analysis of data or statistics

I'm not sure if these are in fact antonyms, but the fit seems appropriate in the context of computing.

Comment: Analysis of some sort would be required by any heuristic or it would just be random.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the opposite of "heuristic" would be "deductive".  [Heuristic reasoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) is based on experience or probabilistic approaches that are likely to find adequate solutions. [Deductive reasoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning) is based on provable inferences to reach a logically certain conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Heuristic analytics uses data to support an empirical conclusion.  Deductive analytics uses data to direct a logical conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

In the educational sense of *heuristic* then *didactic* in its sense of "instructing" would be a rough antonym.

In the computer science sense, *classic* is often used as an antonym of the use in an approach, *provable* as an antonym of the results (since with the classic approach we should be able to prove the algorithm, security, speed, memory use, etc. while with a heuristic approach we cannot).

In law, "case-by-case" or "case-by-case analysis" would be antonyms to the heuristic approach.

Answer (score 1):

Heuristic is a woolly word.  Antonyms for *some* common engineering applications are **exhaustive** (approach, algorithm, analysis, etc.), or analysis, etc., **from first principles**.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of Heuristic is Algorithmic.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Ashton. 
Nice to see you here. Answers are nearly always better when they contain a link or two to sources or authorities. Again, welcome.

Comment: Disagree. An algorithm can be either heuristic or deterministic in its positive or negative assertions.

Comment: @MarkHu: You are right that the opposite of a heuristic is *not* algorithmic, but that has nothing to do with determinism. An heuristic can also deterministic. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm, an algorithm can actually be even non-deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, sometimes “Rigorous argument” is used as antonym of “ Heuristic argument”.